# hibernate search - get entity id in composite

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'd like to create a composite and add the entities id (the one in the database) as property. I tried to use f.id() but I can't map it to a long and it seems to be the document id in elasticsearch instead the database index anyway. Here is my code.

```
List<GlobalSearchResult> hits = searchSession.search(Searchable.class)
 .select(f -> f.composite(
    GlobalSearchResult::new,
    f.id(),
    f.field("searchType", String.class),
    f.field("searchName", String.class),
    f.field("searchDescription", String.class),
    f.score()
  ))
 .where(f -> f.simpleQueryString().fields(INDEXED_FIELDS).matching(q))
 .fetchHits( 20 );
```

Is there a smart, elegant way to get the id into GlobalSearchResult or do I have to get the entity and map it? That would be a lot of boilerplate code since I have many classes implementing Searchable.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet of code returns the document ID, but [by default that's the same as the entity ID](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-identifiermapping-basics), so this should work fine for you unless you have an exotic mapping.

Assuming the ID of all targeted types is indeed a Long, you can retrieve the ID as a long [simply by passing `Long.class` to `id()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-projection-id):

EDIT: I didn't notice your code snippet was not compiling. Since you want more than 3 parameters, your "transforming" function (the first parameter to "composite") will receive a list as argument, and you'll need to cast the list elements before you pass them to the `GlobalSearchResult` constructor:

```
List<GlobalSearchResult> hits = searchSession.search(Searchable.class)
 .select(f -> f.composite(
    list -> new GlobalSearchResult(
            (Long) list.get(0),
            (String) list.get(1),
            (String) list.get(2),
            (String) list.get(3),
            (Float) list.get(4)
    ),
    f.id(Long.class),
    f.field("searchType", String.class),
    f.field("searchName", String.class),
    f.field("searchDescription", String.class),
    f.score()
  ))
 .where(f -> f.simpleQueryString().fields(INDEXED_FIELDS).matching(q))
 .fetchHits( 20 );
```

In Hibernate Search 6.2 we aim to provide an easier solution based on Java records and annotations, but that's still work in progress; the [current implementation](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.2/#mapping-projection) only works for field projections, and ID/score projections will come later ([HSEARCH-4574](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-4574)).

Comment: Thank you that answers my question perfectly. Nevertheless, I found out that the code produces an error since the fields provided in composite() are 5 and if I understand correctly only 2 or 3 are allowed.

Comment: Ah, right. I didn't notice your code snippet was not compiling. Beyond 3 parameters, you'll get a list as argument to your "transforming" function, and you need to cast. I edited my answer.